# Image loading Illegal Argument Exception error

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception, image-loading

I'm currently programming a game and trying to load and image from an `ImageLoader` class and I keep receiving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1338)
at game.ImageLoader.getImage(ImageLoader.java:24)
at game.TestPanel.<init>(TestPanel.java:38)
at game.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:26)
```

Here is the code to my class that's calling the `ImageLoader` class, yet I also receive an error on my catch block:

```
    public TestPanel ()
        {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader myLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
            backdrop = loader.getImage("resources/Asteroid.jpg");
            ImageLoader test = new ImageLoader();
            ship = test.getImage("resources/Alien-Ship.png");
            InputStream pointStream = myLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/path_1.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner (pointStream);
            objectPath = new PathPoints(s);
            squid = objectPath.getStart();


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("Could not load: " + e);
        }
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
```

And here is the code for my `ImageLoader` class:

```
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class ImageLoader {

    public Image loadedImage;

        public ImageLoader(){


        }

        public Image getImage(String s){
        try
                {
                    ClassLoader myLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                    InputStream imageStream = myLoader.getResourceAsStream(s);
                    loadedImage = ImageIO.read(imageStream);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Could not load: " + e);
                }

                return loadedImage;
         }

        }
```

Why is it throwing null!, I have tried to change the path of `resources/Asteroid.jpg` to `/resources/Asteroid.jpg` yet it changed nothing.

`resources` relates to my classpath because it is the package in which I am storing my image and point resources in. Since I am not able ot upload an image of my tree it is as follows:

Project - MyGame

Packages:

play - Contians all class files and code

resources - contains all images and documents

Comment: Which line of code throws this exception? Can you point it out?

Comment: @PM 77-1 It's in the ImageLoader class `loadedImage = ImageIO.read(imageStream);`

Comment: Before this line put:  `System.out.println(myLoader); System.out.println(imageStream);`  If you know how to use a debugger you can check these values w/o adding `println()` calls.